# opengl light problem

Tags: opengl, colors, lighting

I have loaded an object, and when I draw the object, I set the color to green..
After drawing the object, I draw lines in red.

It all worked out fine. The problem arise when I input lighting properties.
When I create a light source, everything where the light projects becomes white. 
Why does the lighting over writes my color? And how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

The code you have would help in diagnosing the problem. This sounds like a problem with setting up the materials for the items (which define how they interact with the lights).

You may want to look into the [glColorMaterial](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml) function. The following snippet of code will set this up:

```
GLfloat mat_specular[] = {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0};
GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 10.0 };
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```